# How can a person living in the tropics be better prepared to travel to snowy areas?

Tags: planning, tips-and-tricks, snow

I live in a hot and humid part of India, and plan to vacation for a week at one of the hill-stations close to the Himalayas, to experience snow for the first time. This might involve a bit of light hiking.

To not keep the topic too broad, my questions are about:
1. Handling the cold
2. Options for food and drink
3. Being prepared for snow

**Handling the cold:**
Not being accustomed to cold and not having much of a fat deposit beneath my skin, what would be the basic warm clothing required? I'm guessing [thermal tops](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=thermal%20top&client=ubuntu&hs=Csc&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3drRzsHQAhVLOY8KHejtAp8Q_AUICCgB&biw=1568&bih=811), [long johns](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=long%20john&client=ubuntu&hs=aXx&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqgrLUzsHQAhWBuo8KHWMcCXgQ_AUICCgB&biw=1568&bih=811#channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=long%20john%20winter), wollen sweater, jacket, wollen socks and normal leather boots would be the basics (am basically looking to purchase boots that I can use in the snow and then use it back at my hometown, with formal wear so that it wouldn't be a waste of money). Would [mittens](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mittens&client=ubuntu&hs=dJI&channel=fs&biw=1568&bih=811&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk07mZ0MHQAhUFN48KHT4ZCrQQ_AUIBigB), [muffler](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=wollen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uPs2WMLDAoyFvASMhIHoBQ#channel=fs&q=muffler) and [monkey cap](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=wollen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uPs2WMLDAoyFvASMhIHoBQ#channel=fs&q=monkey%20cap) be necessary too?
When shopping, should I give preference to wollen clothing or ones made with fleece?
If I get close to catching a fever or catch a cold, is it a sign that I should get out of the hilly areas ASAP?

**Options for food and drink**:
What kinds of food naturally keep the body warm (I heard peanuts do) and what to avoid? I'm considering carrying a bottle of curd too, as it gives energy for physically demanding times. [This website](http://www.hbbostonamc.org/docs/winterfood.html) mentions bread with peanut butter and dry fruits. As for drinks, I guess only water in a thermos flask would be ideal? What about soft drinks (sugar = carbohydrates)? Would carrying packets of soup powder or instant noodles be good if I can find a place to heat water and prepare soup?

**Being prepared for snow**:
I understand I shouldn't walk on snow with a jeans pant, since it'd get wet from the snow. Since I have a two piece raincoat (one piece as a pant and the other piece like a large jacket), would it be advisable to wear the raincoat pant over the jeans pant and tuck it into the boot?
Would there be any issues wearing a thin [money pouch](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=money%20pouch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=UgY3WLDDJ_Dx8AfwuJbwCw#channel=fs&q=money%20pouch%20waist) below all those layers of clothing?

**Location Update:**
A possible trek in Jan to [Triund](http://triund.in/triund/TRIUND.html) or [Dhanaulti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhanaulti) or [Shimla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimla) or [Manali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manali,_Himachal_Pradesh).

Comment: Getting boots that look good for formal wear but have the studs and/or deep ridges you need to walk on snow and ice would be difficult.

Comment: One option there would be snow grips ([example](http://www.millets.co.uk/footwear/106397-yak-trax-walker-snow-grips.html)) that clip on around any shoe. Fine for walking in shallow snow and icy roads (though to be honest just regular boots are fine if it's shallow and you're careful). If you're planning to do very long hikes in deep snow though, it's probably worth getting proper snow boots (try them on before buying - when I bought some online despite being the right size I could barely walk in them).

Comment: What kind of temperatures are we talking, around freezing or substantially lower?

Comment: If wanting to not spend/waste money, see if you can rent proper hiking and cold weather equipment.

Comment: Temperatures are usually at 1 or 2 degree Celsius, but can go to sub-zero too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimla#Climate

Comment: Shimla isn't exactly "snowy" for most part. Day temperatures are a cool 10-13 degree celsius. Nights can get chilly but are still above freezing point. Its the wind you need to watch out for. You don't need any hiking gear, snow grip boots if you plan to stay in shimla only or go till nearby place like Kufri.

Comment: @Nav, please edit your original post with the destination.

Comment: Food and drink is easy: Anything warm will warm you up. Hence hot tea, hot chocolate, etc. The rest is rather opinion-based in my opinion.

Comment: One of the objectives of the trip is to experience snow, so we should assume the OP will do at least day trips to snowy locations.

Comment: I'll be rubbing oil on my head. Hope that'll help prevent heat and moisture loss. I don't think Kendall Mint Cake is available in India, but am considering Chikkis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chikki

Comment: Go easy on the alcohol. Alcohol can make you feel "warm" inside but it drains your body's reserves.

Comment: Don't  rub oil on yourself !!! !Just wear a hat !!

Comment: You're going to have to buy a sweater.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cold is easier to tackle than Hot; you can just add more layers.

**The most important thing is to keep dry**; buy/rent water and wind proof equipment.

Prefer buying a lightweight coat under which you can add layers (t-shirt, long sleeve, sweater...) instead of a big bulky coat.

You can also get boot covers that will protect the lower part of your pants if walking in the snow.

Mittens vs. Gloves: Mittens are warmer (and cheaper) at the cost of a loss in dexterity.

Mufflers ? don't know about that.

Money belt, why not; not a big issue; just keep some loose change in easy to access pockets so you do not have to remove all your cloths to get to it.

Food: Just eat what you are used to eat when you are in town; hot food is always comforting but not practical when hiking; get granola bars (nuts, chocolate...) they keep well, and can help you get some energy into you if getting hungry before getting a proper meal.

Soup Powder? yes, soup is good, but will you have access to hot/boiling water ? that is the question.

Drinks: Water is always the best choice, if seriously hiking, maybe a "sport drink" can help in the long run.; hot chocolate/chai is comforting

If doing day-hiking (get back to the hotel each night) , your best bet is to only bring dried food (nuts, granola bars, chocolate, dried fruits); don't bother with soup powder, noddles... accesss to hot water will be problematic.

Comment: One problem with renting seems to be cheating and sub-standard products: http://www.manalishimlaexpert.com/manali/rohtang-snow-charges.html.

Comment: Second the bit of layers.  I've spent basically my whole life in hot desert climates (so we get cold winter nights--but with heat in the house so we don't experience much of that) but I've been in some pretty cold places.  The answer is layers so you can add as needed.  At least one should be windproof.  -30C with adequate clothes, no problem.  (Now, the altitude was another matter....)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer Max. I had asked the question for two reasons. To know best practices and to confirm my assumptions. Some of the assumptions remain unanswered. The ones about curd, mufflers, mittens, soup powder, money pouch.

Comment: I don't know what curd is  in that context. ?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Am surprised at the Wikipedia entry for curd. In India curd (similar to yogurt) or 'dahi' is: *made by boiling and cooling the milk to 30-40°C and adding a spoonful of curd. Now curd has lactic acid bacteria or lactobacillus. This bacteria multiplies itself in the ambient temperature of 30-40°C and in few hours ferments the milk to form curd*. Mufflers are a part of winter clothing that's wrapped around the neck: http://ureadthis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Winter-Muffler.jpeg

Comment: how would you manage your curd ? it seems to be a hassle when in vacation; did you intend bringing it with you or make it (or have it made) at your hotel/accomodaton ?

Comment: Personally, I hate "mufflers" they always get tangled everywhere; have a look at "Neck Warmer" instead

Comment: Neck warmers look good. The reason I had asked about mufflers though, is about whether it really is necessary to keep the neck warm. I see that mittens/gloves would be required to prevent frostbite. Curd is available readymade in packets and I intend to empty it into a bottle. As a source of energy. http://scratchkart.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/heritage-total-curd-600x600.jpg